# Setting up passport-jwt authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, jwt

I'm having some trouble setting up `passport-jwt` with my `express` api server.

On the front end I'm using `ember.js` to post to the `/auth` route the credentials that should authenticate the session and then the library in `ember.js` will handle sending the token in subsequent requests.

I followed [this tutorial](http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/05/29/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-passport/) loosely and switched out their `passport-http` with `passport-jwt` instead, setting it up with the example in [the git repo](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt).

In my `server.js` I have required passport and set it up as middleware using `app.use(passport.initialize());`

At the bottom of the `server.js` file I call my api routes file with `app.use('/api/v1', '/app/routes/api');`

My `app/routes/api.js` file looks has a section for adding and getting users like this

```
router.route('/users')
  .post(function(req,res) { user.addUser(req,res) })
  .get(function(req,res) { user.getAllUsers(req,res) });
```

Which are references to exports in the `api/user.js` file which look like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../../models/user');

module.exports.addUser = function(req, res) {
  var user = new User(req.body.user);

  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({user: user});
  });
};

module.exports.getAllUsers = function(req, res) {
  User.find(function(err, users) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json({users: users});
  });
};
```

The model is pretty straight forward, it attempts to hash the password on save provided it hasn't changed (I'm assuming this is for `PUT` requests) along with a password verification class method

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

UserSchema.pre('save',function(callback){
    var user = this;

    if(!user.isModified('password')) return callback();

    bcrypt.genSalt(5, function(err, salt){
        if (err) return callback(err);

        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash){
            if (err) return callback(err);
            user.password = hash;
            callback();
        });
    });
});

UserSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

For my other API endpoints I am passing in my `isAuthenticated` method from the `controllers/auth.js` like so

```
router.route('/followers')
  .post(authController.isAuthenticated, function(req,res) { follower.addFollower(req,res) })
  .get(authController.isAuthenticated, function(req,res) { follower.getAllFollowers(req,res) });
```

That export in the controller file looks like

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();

var passport = require('passport');
var JWTStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');

var opts = {};
opts.secretOrKey = process.env.PASSPORT_SECRET || 'secretsauce';
passport.use(new JWTStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done){
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, function(err, user){
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (!user) { return done(null,false); }
        user.verifyPassword(password, function(err,isMatch){
            if (err) { return done(err, false); }
            if(!isMatch) { return done(null,false); }
            done(null, user);
        });
    });
}));

exports.isAuthenticated = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session : false });
```

I think this area is where I'm getting confused on how I'm supposed to authenticate with the express server. I can add users and their passwords are being hashed correctly but how do I actually authenticate a user. Specifically how would I go about authorizing them on the `POST` to the `/auth` route? I am using postman to test the API so if someone could maybe explain how to test with a jwt in postman that would be cool. I know I have to set a header to the token I get from authenticating but I am stuck understanding how to authenticate.

Comment: I believe `passport-jwt` works only if you already have a token in your possession. You probably should add authentication endpoint using eg. `passport-local` that verifies the user by their username and password, and gives them the token. Once you have the token you just pass it in the headers and `passport-jwt` will handle rest.

Comment: Ah okay, that might explain a few things I've seen in some tutorials with some modules being included but I didn't really understand how or why they were being included.

Answer (score 2):

In your routes you should be including passport.authenticate functions that checks whether there is a valid token.